# Save daily scores with Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to save users' last 2 weeks scores daily, then using them in my app,  so others can see user's daily scores (for last 2 weeks). Is it possible to make it with  Google Play Game Services ?

Answer (score 0):

[Play Game Services already creates daily, weekly, and all time snapshots of leaderboards for you](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards#leaderboard_time_frames). To create a leaderboard with a custom slice of time (e.g. two weeks) would require some more work on your part. You would need to get the scores from a leaderboard and then filter / present the UI yourself.